# How to use libpurple in Java?

Tags: java, libpurple

the libpurple it written in cpp,Is it possible to use it in java application with cross-platform feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can call native code from Java via [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or (easier) [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).